# Is it important to add wp_insert_post() in a varrible?

Tags: php, wordpress

Do i always have to put wp_insert_post() in a variable like

```
$new_post = wp_insert_post($args);
```

Or it's just a preference?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to. [`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) returns the ID of the post that was created if it was successful (*or 0 on failure*). This is handy if you want to use the newly created post for something else later on.